# Python: return value from function without waiting to finish it

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, background-process, function-calls

I am new to python so not sure how to achieve this but I want to run one function which will return some dummy value without waiting to finish it and the function must finish the task asynchronously.

Like:

```
msg = {
     "status": "Process is initiated."
}

def b():
    print ("3")
    time.sleep(5)
    fh = open("hello.txt","w")
    fh.write("Hello World")
    print ("4")
    fh.close()

def a():
    print ("1")
    x = b()
    print (x)
    print ("2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a()


Desired Output:
    1
    {"status": Process is Initiated."}
    2

and function b should work in background and finish it work asynchronously. In this case After 5 seconds it should write into the file.
```

Comment: Which line of code printed `msg`?

Comment: That "dummy" value is typically called a "promise" (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/promise). It's a quite well-known pattern. For asynchronous programming you'll need to use asyncio (built-in) / tornado / multiprocessing

Comment: @JosephK.: Ideally I want msg to be returned by b() to show this message to the GUI and the execution inside b() should be asynchronous.

Comment: @viddik13: My dummy value means the "msg" variable which I have defined in the example. I want to get msg as a response just after call to b() but b function should run asynchronously. Hope you understand my problem now. If you any sample code please help me out.